# Angry JAXB Parser for valid XML?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the XML below:

```
<paths>
  <edge from='l2' to='l0'>
    <path>
        <NTStep symbol='XferObjOut' reverse='false' from='l2' to='o2040'>
          <NTStep symbol='FlowsTo' reverse='false' from='o2053' to='v1033' index='430'>
              <asgnRef reverse='false' from='v923' to='v924'/>
            <paramRef reverse='false' from='v924' to='v1033' index='326'/>
          </NTStep>
          <asgnRef reverse='false' from='v1033' to='v1032'/>
        </NTStep>
    </path>
  </edge>
</paths>
```

Which gets JAXB all in a tizzy:

```
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [FATAL_ERROR]: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Step'. No child element '{step}' is expected at this point. 
     Location: line 10 of file:/Users/gestalt/Desktop/test2/new.xml
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Step'. No child element '{step}' is expected at this point.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:142)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:151)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:169)
    at Test.main(Test.java:28)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Step'. No child element '{step}' is expected at this point.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
```

However...

xmllint validates the xml / schema no problem, and the same code appears to work on another system.

Further, if any one of the aRef or pRef lines are removed, the error does not occur...

The Schema is below. I apologize for the length but I new to this business and am thus preferring completeness to soundness...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       jxb:version="2.1">

<!-- SIMPLE TYPES ==========================================================-->

<xs:simpleType name="NodeName">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
    <xs:pattern value="v[0-9]+|u[0-9]+|l[0-9]+|o[0-9]+|f[0-9]+"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="GrammarNTSymbol">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
    <xs:enumeration value="ArrElemFT"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="FTImm"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="FlowsTo"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="InstFldFT"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Label2Obj"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Label2Prim"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Label2PrimArrEl"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Label2PrimFld"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Label2Ref"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="LabelObjIn"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Obj2Prim"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Obj2Ref"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Obj2Sink"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Prim2Sink"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Src2Sink"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="XferObjOut"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="T1"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="T2"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="T3"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="T4"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="TemporarySymbol">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
    <xs:pattern value="%[0-9]+"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- BASE STEP TYPES =======================================================-->

<xs:complexType name="BaseStep" abstract="true">
  <xs:attribute name="reverse" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="from" type="NodeName" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="to" type="NodeName" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="MaybeIndexedStep" abstract="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="BaseStep">
      <xs:attribute name="index" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- Head of the 'step' substitution group, serves as a placeholder for any
     kind of element that can appear as a sub-step of a non-terminal step. -->
<xs:element name="step" type="BaseStep" abstract="true"/>

<!-- TERMINAL STEP TYPES ===================================================-->

<xs:complexType name="TerminalStep" abstract="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="BaseStep"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="IndexedTerminalStep" abstract="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="TerminalStep">
      <xs:attribute name="index" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- More correctly, steps that stay within the same context. -->
<xs:complexType name="IntraProceduralStep">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="TerminalStep"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="arrLoadPrim" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="arrStorePrim" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="arrStoreRef" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="asgnPrim" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="asgnRef" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="prim2Prim" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="prim2Ref" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="prim2SinkByPrim" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="prim2SinkByRef" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="ref2Prim" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="ref2Ref" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="ref2SinkByPrim" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="ref2SinkByRef" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="sinkLabel" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="srcLabel" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="statStorePrim" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="statStoreRef" type="IntraProceduralStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>

<xs:complexType name="CallStep">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="IndexedTerminalStep"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="paramPrim" type="CallStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="paramRef" type="CallStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>

<xs:complexType name="ReturnStep">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="IndexedTerminalStep"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="retPrim" type="ReturnStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="retRef" type="ReturnStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>

<!-- Steps (other than calls and returns) that cross to a new context. Still
     expected to retain a consistent view of the stack. -->
<xs:complexType name="CtxtCrossingStep">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="IndexedTerminalStep"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="label2Prim" type="CtxtCrossingStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="label2Ref" type="CtxtCrossingStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="new" type="CtxtCrossingStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>

<!-- Steps that can arbitrarily set the context, even to otherwise invalid
     states. -->
<xs:complexType name="CtxtSettingStep">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="IndexedTerminalStep"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="statLoadPrim" type="CtxtSettingStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="statLoadRef" type="CtxtSettingStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>

<xs:complexType name="StoreStep">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="IndexedTerminalStep"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="storePrim" type="StoreStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="storeRef" type="StoreStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>

<xs:complexType name="LoadStep">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="IndexedTerminalStep"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="loadPrim" type="LoadStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>
<xs:element name="loadRef" type="LoadStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>

<!-- NON-TERMINAL STEP TYPES ===============================================-->

<xs:complexType name="NonTerminalStep" abstract="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="MaybeIndexedStep">
      <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="step" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2">
      <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <jxb:property name="subSteps"/>
            </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="GrammarNTStep">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="NonTerminalStep">
      <xs:attribute name="symbol" type="GrammarNTSymbol" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="NTStep" type="GrammarNTStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>

<xs:complexType name="TemporaryStep">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="NonTerminalStep">
      <xs:attribute name="symbol" type="TemporarySymbol" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="TempStep" type="TemporaryStep" substitutionGroup="step"/>

<!-- TOP-LEVEL ELEMENTS ====================================================-->

<xs:complexType name="Path">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="NTStep">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <jxb:property name="topStep"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Edge">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="path" type="Path" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <jxb:property name="paths"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="from" type="NodeName" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="to" type="NodeName" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="PathsList">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="edge" type="Edge" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <jxb:property name="edges"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="paths" type="PathsList"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the XML schema you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining about an element called NTStep and there's no such element in the sample you posted. So I would examine things carefully to check that the XML you are processing is the XML you think you are processing.

Comment: quite right. I apologize. I renamed the NTStep as Step in this post incompletely, not in the code. I have adjusted the post accordingly. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Your revised input document is valid against the schema when validated using Saxon, Xerces, or libxml. So I suspect you are still showing us different data from the data that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thank you for trying it again. I have reuploaded the source absolutely verbatim for sanity.
However, as I mentioned, the code works fine on two ubuntu machines and checks out on the xmllint on both systems. However, the JAXB Unmarshalling excepiton still stands on OSX 10.6.8, java version "1.6.0_51", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-10M4509)

Comment: I'd suggest trying it with the Apache version of Xerces. The version of Xerces bundled in JDK 1.6 is notoriously buggy.

Comment: Michael, that fixed it. Pretty sad the packaged version is so lousy, but thanks for your help!